# Python if statement troubleshooting

Tags: python, python-2.7

Python Version : 2.7

Just wondering what is wrong with the following code :

```
def bmi_cat(bmi):
    if bmi < 18.5:
        return "underweight"
    elif (bmi >=18.5 or bmi < 25):
        return "normal"
    elif (bmi >=25 or bmi < 30):
        return "overweight"
    else:
        return "obese"
```

Basically if i enter 17 it gives me the correct answer, but it gives me normal for anything above 18.5 (3000 gives normal instead of obese,etc...)

Comment: python allows you to write your conditionals as `18.5 <= bmi < 25`, for increased readability and clarity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `and` not `or`... it needs to meet **both** criteria... You can also write it in Python as `if 18.5 <= bmi < 25` to make it clearer and avoid this...

Also consider looking at http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html which can do this sort of thing for you and will scale better if you had larger ranges. Take a look at the [grade example](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#other-examples).

Answer (score 4):

It's because you're using `or`. If `bmi >= 18.5` is true then the whole condition of the first `elif` will be true. Use `and` instead.

Or better yet, *don't* include two conditions in one. When the first elif is reached, you *know* that `bmi >= 18.5`, if it wasn't then the first if would have been entered. Hence, we can rewrite this as

```
if bmi < 18.5:
    return "underweight"
if bmi < 25:
    return "normal"
if bmi < 30:
    return "overweight"
return "obese"
```

We also don't need `elif` because `return` ends the function.

Comment: When the first elif is reached, you know that `bmi >= 18.5`, not that `bmi > 25`.

Comment: @AirThomas That's absolutely right, just a typo. Anyway, corrected.

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
def bmi_cat(bmi):
    if bmi < 18.5:
        return "underweight"
    elif (bmi >=18.5 and bmi < 25):
        return "normal"
    elif (bmi >=25 and bmi < 30):
        return "overweight"
    else:
        return "obese"
```

If you check:

```
elif (bmi >=18.5 or bmi < 25):
```

it gives True for every value bigger or equal to 18.5

Comment: There are better explanations below and in practice you should definitely use @arshajii code instead my corrections.

Answer (score 1):

`>=` means "greater than or equals". So `bmi >= 18.5` will be true for any number that is equal to 18.5 or above.

Because you've used the Boolean operator `or`, the whole statement will be true if the number is 18.5 or above. Hence why it works for 3000.

You probably meant to do `bmi >= 18.5 and bmi <25`, which will be True if both conditions are True.